# How to scroll Twitter/X advanced search popup with Selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, twitter

I'm using selenium and python to web scrape twitter. I am stuck when it comes to scrolling in a popup window. To recreate this (on a desktop sized screen)...

- go to twitter.com/home
- In the top right corner find the search bar and type something. My test case is '#BostonStrong'
- On the next results screen, again in the top right corner click 'Advanced Search'. This is the popup I am trying to scroll.

This gives you a popup window with many search features. I need to scroll down to the 'Language' dropdown menu and also the 'Dates' section.

I have tried my normal method of scrolling which is something like this:

`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`

or if I want to scroll to a specific element (such as the Dates section)

```
element_to_scroll = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="SELECTOR_9"]')

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element_to_scroll)
```

Nothing happens. No errors. What else can I do?

Comment: First of all, do you *need* to scroll? Even if the elements aren't visible on the screen, they still exist, and can be clicked.